# Llvm how to access global array elements

Tags: llvm

Can someone please explain me what is wrong with this code?

I think this should fetch the second argument from global array, but in fact it silently crushes somewhere inside JIT compilation routine.

My suppositions:

1. GEP instruction calculates memory address of the element by applying offset and returns pointer.
2. load instruction loads value referenced by given pointer (it dereferences a pointer, in other words).
3. ret instruction exits function and passes given value to caller.

Seems like I've missed something basic, but time point from which i should give up looking for answer myself is gone and i have to seek for help.

```
@arr = common global [256 x i64], align 8

define i64 @iterArray() {
entry:
  %0 = load i64* getelementptr inbounds ([256 x i64]* @arr, i32 1, i32 0)
  ret i64 %0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requested the 257th item in a 256-item array, and that's a problem.

The first index given to a gep instruction means how many steps are made through the value operand - and here the value operand is not an array but a *pointer to an array*. That means every step there skips the entire size of the array forward - and that's why the gep actually asks for the 257th item. Using 0 as the first gep index will probably fix the problem. Then using 1 as the 2nd index will get you the 2nd item in the array, which is what you wanted. Read more about it here: http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#what-is-the-first-index-of-the-gep-instruction

Alternatively, it's more appropriate here to use the [`extractvalue`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractvalue-instruction) instruction, which is similar to gep with implicitly uses a 0 for the first index (and there are a couple of other differences).

Regarding why the compiler crashes, I'm not sure - I'm guessing that while normally such a memory access would compile fine (and at runtime either generate a segfault or just return a bad value), here you specifically requested the gep to be `inbounds`, which means that a bounds check is done - and it will fail here - so a [poison value](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#poison-values) is returned, which means your function is now effectively `load undef`. I'm not sure what LLVM does with `load undef` - it should probably be optimized out and the function be made to just `return undef` - but maybe it did something different which led to a rejection of your code.

Comment: Hello Oak, thank you for your answer.

This code doesn't behave any different. The first index here is zero, right?

`
    ; ModuleID = 'test'

    @arr = common global [256 x i64], align 8

    define i64 @iterArray() {
    entry:
      %0 = load i64* getelementptr inbounds ([256 x i64]* @arr, i32 0, i32 1)
      ret i64 %0
    }

    declare void @abort()
`

Comment: Update: I have solved this issue (finally) by manually allocating memory buffer for this global variable. Isn't the jit compiler supposed to do such things?

`
    uint64_t *arr = new uint64_t[256];
    EE->addGlobalMapping(globArr, arr);
`

Comment: @user1736596 glad to see you solved it, maybe add this solution as a separate answer? In any case you still need to fix the indices (or better yet, use `extractvalue`).